# Filter out broken pipe errors

Tags: io, go, system-calls, broken-pipe, epipe

I'm getting an `error` returned from an `io.Copy` call, to which I've passed a socket (`TCPConn`) as the destination. It's expected that the remote host will simply drop the connection when they've had enough, and I'm not receiving anything from them.

When the drop occurs, I get this error:

```
write tcp 192.168.26.5:21277: broken pipe
```

But all I have is an `error` interface. How can I differentiate broken pipe errors from other kinds of error?

```
if err.Errno == EPIPE...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The broken pipe error is defined in the syscall package. You can use the equality operator to compare the error to the one in syscall. Check http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#constants for a complete list of syscall errors. Search "EPIPE" on the page and you will find all the defined errors grouped together.

```
if err == syscall.EPIPE {
    /* ignore */
}
```

If you wish to get the actual errno number (although it is pretty useless) you can use a type assertion:

```
if e, ok := err.(syscall.Errno); ok {
    errno = uintptr(e)
}
```

Comment: This looks like a winner, I'll give a go.

Comment: Yes it did. In addition I had to type-assert to `net.OpError` first, then compare `opErr.Err == syscall.EPIPE`.

Answer (score 10):

As of go 1.13, you can use [errors.Is](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#Is) instead of type assertions.

```
if errors.Is(err, syscall.EPIPE) {
  // broken pipe
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Having all but an `error` interface is enough to perform a type assertion or a type switch to reveal the concrete type held by the interface.

Comment: That doesn't tell me where the concrete type for this error is held.