# Filter out broken pipe errors from template execution

Tags: io, go, system-calls, broken-pipe, epipe

This is similar to [Filter out broken pipe errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003692/filter-out-broken-pipe-errors) , but with complications - when a user presses the "stop" button on their browser while a template is executing (html/template.Execute or text/template.Execute), a broken pipe error occurs.

However, I believe that the error returned by the text/template package is simply of type *errors.errorString as the broken pipe message appears to be wrapped in some other informational text and so no type assertion can be made to net.OpErr for comparison purposes.

For example, a typical broken pipe error string would look like

`write tcp 127.0.0.1:60739: broken pipe`

A broken pipe error string returned by an executing template looks like:

`template: header.html:1:0: executing "header.html" at <div id="header...>: write tcp 127.0.0.1:60739: broken pipe`

I have a production web application written in Go and am sick of visually filtering out broken pipe errors in the rest of my error logs but right now I have no clue how to filter out broken pipe other than using something dirty like strings.Contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a logging issue. I'd rather have more information in my logs and have to filter it, than try and track down a bug when this error message is the only trace of the problem.

As you mentioned, the error is created via `errors.New`. All you have is a string, so the only way to filter this error from executing the template is going to be by inspecting said string, probably with `strings.Contains`.

Another way to handle this would be to wrap your `io.Writer` to catch the `broken pipe`, then silently throw away any subsequent writes.

Comment: I wrapped the writer, caught the broken pipe and ignored it... thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Just going to post what ended up being the wrapper that worked for me.  If anyone sees anything wrong, feel free to chime in.

```
type templateWriter struct {
    writer io.Writer
}

func (w templateWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := w.writer.Write(p)
    if err != nil {
        // Filter out broken pipe (user pressed "stop") errors
        if nErr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
            if nErr.Err == syscall.EPIPE {
                return n, nil
            }
        }
    }
    return n, err
}
```