# What's the bad effect of "http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls"?

Tags: go, httpresponse, httpserver

My server behaves well though I find the exception of "http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls". This exception doesn't cause my server panic or behaving weirdly.

I have searched a lot but only found how to solve this problem. There's no doc describing the bad effects of the exception. Could someone help me find why "http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls" is an exception and what the bad effects are that it causes? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have read the source code [here](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1052):

[image]

When calling `WriteHeader` multitimes，it only prints a log and then does nothing. It seems that calling `WriteHeader` multitimes doesn't cause the server behaves weiredly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple response.WriteHeader calls in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961764/multiple-response-writeheader-calls-in-go)

Comment: @Zoyd My question is different from that. I want to know the bad effects of "http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls" while that one explains why that's impossible that call `WriteHeader` again after having called `WriteHeader`.

Comment: The answer shows that calling WriteHeader multiple times doesn’t make sense. Therefore, if it happens, it necessarily points to some kind of mistake or unintended behaviour.

Comment: Though it doesn't make sense, it's ok if it doesn't cause something behave weirdly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only write a response header once before it is sent to the client. Because your code is attempting to write a response header after it has been sent to the client, the client will never see the final response you are trying to send.

You either have a bug where the client is getting the incorrect response which you later revised, or you have a bug where you are executing the wrong code after the correct response header has been written. Either way it's a bug.

Comment: From [the source code](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1052), the client won't get s second  response header.

Comment: @flyer: of course, because you can't really respond more than once. The server is warning you about a problem with your code so you can correct it.

Answer (score 2):

The bad effect is that the actual result will most probably be different from what you expect. If you call `WriteHeader(200)` on line 10, and later on line 50 you call, on the same `ResponseWriter`,  `WriteHeader(404)` what do you expect the response code to be? `404`, or `200`?

`WriteHeader` ignores subsequent calls and tells you about it by logging that message, so that when you're getting `200` instead of `404` as you probably expect, you just take a look at the server logs and you know what's up. The message is there to help you.